# MySQL fetchall() - how to get data inside a dict rather than inside a tuple

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I've a table having columns as `id`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. I executed the query in this way.

```
cur.execute(query)
row = cur.fetchall()
```

Can I get the data of `row` inside a `dict` ,ie I want to pass this result as a result to an **api**.

`cur.fetchall()` will yield me result in the following format `((id,col1,col2,col3),(id,col1,col2,col3),(id,col1,col2,col3))`

Can I get result in

```
[
   {id:value,col1:value,col2:value,col3:value},
   {id:value,col1:value,col2:value,col3:value},
   {id:value,col1:value,col2:value,col3:value}
]
```

I know this concept that I can loop around `fetchall()`, and get values using dictionary concept, ie

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   id = row['id']
   col1 = row['col1']
   and so on...
```

**Can I pass `rows` as a dictionary??**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to "zip" the resulting values with `cursor.description`:

```
columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
rows = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: This is same like looping around `fetchall()` and creating a dict, which is time-consuming. Is there some direct solution?

Comment: @user1162512 I am afraid there is nothing built-in. I've been using this approach for a while whenever I needed. As an alternative approach, you can use an ORM which would hide how it does it, but would give you model objects with a "dot" access to the fields..

Comment: @user1162512 btw, from what I recall, Django uses the same approach to match the model fields with results of the query.

Comment: I've been an avid user of Django and knew this feature in Django, but didnt knew how it works, hence wanted to know the same for raw MySQL. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user1162512 yeah, and there is also `information_schema.columns` used, see  https://github.com/django/django/blob/e9282747a4ba99adc7e0f677b3a897830df51732/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py#L53.

Answer (score 31):

If you are using `mysql-connector` library to connect to the database, the easy way is to set `dictionary` to `True` inside **cursor** function:

```
db = connector.connect(**config)

cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Comment: TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'

Comment: @caram As you figured out already, that's because you are using `MySQLdb` connector, this solution is for `mysql-connector`.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to do it is to use the `DictCursor`:

```
import MySQLdb
...
cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

You can also set this for all cursors generated by `db` by passing the `cursor_class` parameter to `connect`

Documentation for the different types of cursors is here: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#using-and-extending

Comment: Excellent, this should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified a little alecxe's answer to zip each row inside cursor loop. Might be helpful in case you have a large table, so you won't hold all rows in memory.

```
cursor = db.execute_sql("select * from something")
columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    row = dict(zip(columns, row))
    print(row)
```