# Get value of row from mysqlphp in flask python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have table like:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVBuJ.png)

I want to print password only like:

```
samer
```

I tried this:

```
mysql = MySQL()
flask.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
flask.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
flask.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
flask.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'web'
mysql.init_app(flask)

@flask.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']
    # print(password)
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE password=%s', (password,))
    user = cur.fetchall()
    print(user)
    # if password is wrong, user will be None else Dict
    if user is not None:
        print(user['password'])
    else:
        print("User not found")
```

but i get this error:

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

i can print result if i use:

```
for row in user:
    passw = row['password']
```

but i need to use first method, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL fetchall() - how to get data inside a dict rather than inside a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020839/mysql-fetchall-how-to-get-data-inside-a-dict-rather-than-inside-a-tuple)

Comment: @Goion No, I don't need to use for loop, i just want to access password directly

Comment: You just wrote code and didn't really explain what you are doing. I assume you want to fetch all users with certain password. So obviously you have to iterate over all the rows that get returned.

Comment: Although this code makes no sense. Why are you doing it though.

Comment: @Goion I am using this code for authentication password from DB and password entered by user, i really need to make loop over all users but i use this code just for test. I edit my question by add full code.

Comment: You should be checking `f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{email}' AND password='{password}'"`. Also you only need to fetch once.

Comment: @Goion I tried it but it returns the same error 'None', i use import bcrypt instead of import MySQL, MySQLdb but still the same problem occurs.

Comment: It is hard to help you since you are not clearly conveying the information. The question never mentions bcrypt and the based off the screenshot seems like the passwords are saved as plain text. You need to add all the information in the question. Also, what if your query parameters are bad or maybe the connection to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `fetchall` call with `fetchone`:

```
 cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
 cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE password=%s', (password,))
 user = cur.fetchone()
 # if password is wrong, user will be None else Dict
 if user is not None:
     print(user['password'])
 else:
     print("User not found")
```

Comment: I tried this but i get this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Thank you for reply, i get 'User not found' but i dont understand why. I have record in table